# How to properly use EXISTS in SQL

Tags: sql, exists

I'm having issue with a homework assignment where I have to use EXISTS to filter results where the date is 2016-07-23 but it always returns everything instead. I can get this to work using just inner joins so I must be using EXISTS improperly but I cant figure out where I'm going wrong. I'll include my code below, I'm working in a SQLquery database.

```
select 
    c.last_name, t.trip_name, t.start_location
from 
    customer c
inner join 
    reservation r on c.customer_num = r.customer_num
inner join 
    trip t on t.trip_ID = r.trip_id
where 
    exists (select r.trip_date 
            from reservation r
            where r.trip_date = '2016-07-23');
```

Comment: you have to relate the exists subquery back to a value in the row of the outer query, otherwise the exists value will be the same for every row

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what the desired result should be, but be aware that the two `reservation r` tables/aliases are distinct here (except for the fact that they both draw from the same base table) - there is no correlation between the r values within the join and the r values of the exists clause.

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect the sub-query in your exists statement to the outer query, otherwise everything will return because the exists statement will always evaluate to true:

```
select 
    c.last_name, t.trip_name, t.start_location
from 
    customer c
inner join 
    reservation r on c.customer_num = r.customer_num
inner join 
    trip t on t.trip_ID = r.trip_id
where 
    exists (select r2.trip_date 
            from reservation r2
            where
             r2.customer_num = c.customer_num --connect to current customer
             and r2.trip_date = '2016-07-23');
```

This will give you all customers that have a reservation on 7/23/16.  It's also possible that you might need to connect the sub-query to the trip table by adding this to the where clause:

```
and r2.trip_id = t.trip_id
```

This may be too narrow a filter though (can't say for sure as I don't know your data).

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery results always with the same row, as someone pointed you should reference subquery to main query:

```
select c.last_name, t.trip_name, t.start_location
from customer c
inner join reservation r
on c.customer_num = r.customer_num
inner join trip t
on t.trip_ID = r.trip_id
where exists (
select ri.trip_date 
from reservation ri
where ri.trip_date = r.trip_date);
```

I just guessed that you want to join reservation back to reservation in this awkward way. If you have other date field you want to join, just change it.

Comment: thank you, but all of these still have the same problem. there are only two rows with that date but i'm still getting all the rows in the table when I execute the query.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out you need to join to the outer table to filter records in the outer query.Your query should look like:

```
select c.last_name, t.trip_name, t.start_location
from customer c
inner join reservation r
on c.customer_num = r.customer_num
inner join trip t
on t.trip_ID = r.trip_id
where exists (
select ri.trip_date 
from reservation ri
where r.customner_num = ri.customer_num
AND ri.trip_date = '2016-07-23');
```